# Users creating rota

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

I use devise gem and try to make an application where  I have User and Rota table. I want to let my users create, show, edit, destroy only their own Rota but let the admin do everything. My controllers are:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
 after_action :verify_authorized


 def index
   @users = User.all
 authorize User
   end

 def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 authorize @user
 end

 def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
   authorize @user
   if @user.update_attributes(secure_params)
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
  else
    redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
  end
  end

   def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize user
   user.destroy
   redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
  end

def edit
      @rotum = @user.rota.find_by id: params[:id] # returns nil in case the        record        does    not exist or does not belong to @user
     redirect_to "somewhere", alert: 'You cannot edit this element' if @rotum.blank?
  end

  private

  def secure_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:role)
 end

end





 class RotaController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  before_action :set_rotum, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
   @rota = Rotum.all
   respond_with(@rota)

   end

  def show
   respond_with(@rotum)
  end

  def new
  @rotum = Rotum.new
   respond_with(@rotum)
   end

  def edit
  end

  def create
   @rotum = Rotum.new(rotum_params)
  @rotum.save
   respond_with(@rotum)
  end

   def update
   @rotum.update(rotum_params)
    respond_with(@rotum)
   end

   def destroy
   @rotum.destroy
    respond_with(@rotum)
   end

    private
   def set_rotum
   @rotum = current_user.rota.find(params[:id])
    if @rotum.nil?
   render :html => "Not authorized", :status => 401
   end
   end

     def rotum_params
    params.require(:rotum).permit(:name, :email, :mobile, :category)
    end
    end
```

My Models are like:
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rota, dependent: :destroy

and

class Rotum < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

My terminal executes:

SELECT `rota`.* FROM `rota`  WHERE `rota`.`user_id` = 3

and the error on the page is

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /rota/31

Couldn't find Rotum with 'id'=31 [WHERE `rota`.`user_id` = ?]

So it's certainly creating them fields when I check in IRB but nothing is happening on the PAGE. I have a user_id column on my rota table also now but it's always nil for every rota. How do I change this so that every user has a UNIQUE Rota that they created so that they can only play with their own Rota.

Answer (score 0):

> .. the error on the page is .. `RecordNotFound` ..
>   I have a user_id column on my rota table
>   also now but it's always nil for every rota.

You have asked ActiveRecord to find your `Rotum` with a query like this.

```
select *
from rota
where id = 31
  and user_id = ?
;
```

If *all* records in the `rota` table have a `null` `user_id` the above query will return *zero records*.  When ActiveRecord is unable to `find` any records, it raises a `RecordNotFound` error.

> How do I change this so
>   that every user has a UNIQUE Rota that they created so that they can
>   only play with their own Rota?

First, I recommend adding a **not-null constraint** on `rota.user_id`.

```
alter table rota
alter user_id
set not null
;
```

To require that every user have a rota is a little more complicated.  You could try adding a `rotum_id` to your `users` table and apply a **foreign key constraint**.